# JavaScript Event Delegation - Behavior

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create web-page, and to improve performance, I decide to use event delegation, instead of direct binding, but I came across with strange behavior of event delegation or I missed something...

Here is structure of my HTML

```
<div>
    <section class="myClass" data-link="section 1">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Some text....</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

I want to entire section was clickable, but while clicking `h1` or `p` element in `section` `event.target` on that moment is `h1` or `p` and not `section`, so expression in if statement fails...

```
function delegate(ele) {
    ele.parentNode.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "section" && e.target.classList.contains("myClass")) {
            console.log("delegate " + e.target.getAttribute("data-link"));
        }
    }, false);
}
```

I already have solution with direct binding, but it would be good is achieved in the same result with event delegation.
Here is [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/KMJnA/3/)

```
function direct(ele) {
    [].forEach.call(ele, function (value, index, array) {
        value.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            console.log("direct " + value.getAttribute("data-link"));
        }, false);
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you have wrote, [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/KMJnA/7/), because, `event.target` will refer the clicked element that generated the event.

Comment: @RCV Yes, i know, but, I want to get same result with event delegation as with direct binding.

Comment: OMG. Didn't know `e.target.nodeName`  returns an uppercase string D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution with ***CSS*** [**pointer-events**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

[***jsFiddle with CSS***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/KMJnA/10/)

---

```
.myClass * {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

or with ***JavaScript***

[***jsFiddle with JavaScript***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/KMJnA/9/)

---

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var ele = document.querySelector(".myClass").parentNode;

    delegate(ele);

    function delegate(ele) {
        ele.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            var target = e.target;

            while (!(target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "section" && target.classList.contains("myClass"))) {
                target = target.parentNode;
                if (target === ele) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "section" && target.classList.contains("myClass")) {
                console.log("delegate " + target.getAttribute("data-link"));
            }
        });
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you handled the click, you can walk the visual tree, starting from the target, to find the information you need.
You might seek by type (node name), by tag, ... for the sake of the example, i just seek on element up to get a 'data-link' attribute if i don't find one on the target, but you have many choices here.

Edit : another idea is to use event.currentTarget, to get the element on which you hooked the event.

The updated fiddle will print :

```
delegate call on h1 or p of section 1
```

when you click on h1 or p1

and it will print :

```
delegate section 1
```

when you click on the whole section.

http://jsfiddle.net/KMJnA/4/

```
function delegate(ele) {
    ele.parentNode.addEventListener("click", delegateHandler, false);
}

function delegateHandler (e) {
    var target = e.target;  
    var attribute = target.getAttribute("data-link");
    // if target has no attribute
    // seek it on its parent
    if (!attribute) {
         attribute = target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-link");
    }

    if ( target.classList.contains("myClass") ) { 
         console.log("delegate " + attribute);
        } 
    else console.log('delegate call on h1 or p of ' + attribute);
}
```

Rq : i didn't get why you hook the event on the parent of the element, might be simpler not to do it. :-)

Comment: Thanks, nice solution for static html structure, but if i change structure of html or add dynamic elements, i'll have the same problems;)
I'm trying to avoid to bind all elements with own event handlers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add the event listener to `ele` instead of `ele.parentNode`, and use `this` instead of `e.target`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KMJnA/6/)

```
function delegate(ele) {
    ele.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "section" && this.classList.contains("myClass")) {
            console.log("delegate " + this.getAttribute("data-link"));
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Be aware that `e.target` is the element the event was dispatched on. But in your case you don't want that, you want the element which has the event handler, so use `this` (or `ele`).

Comment: In your case it's not event delegation, you just bind first element with click event.

Comment: +1, If you use `e.target` then it'll reference the clicked element that originated the event, this is right. Check [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KMJnA/7/), it'll help you to visualize the action.

Comment: @Givi Ah, you're right, now I understand the use of `parentNode`... I didn't realize all sections are children of a div.