# live addEventListener mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, addeventlistener

I have jQuery's code:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter","a",function(e){
    //...
});
```

How create the same but with native JavaScript (without jQuery)?

I need only Chrome compatible.

Comment: Dude... talking about cross-browser and stuff, the correct answer to that would be quite long!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Event Delegation - Behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227109/javascript-event-delegation-behavior)

Comment: Event delegation..OMG..Very long ans to copy and paste..

Comment: Talking about cross-browser's solution - I need it work only in Chrome.

Comment: Ok, how to make it "live"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the same functionality, where you can add multiple event listeners to a single element, use the following:

```
addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    if (e.target instanceof HTMLAnchorElement) {
        //...
    }
});
```

That will do the exact same. For other selectors:

```
addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    if (e.target instanceof HTMLAnchorElement) {
        //matches if the element is an <a>
    }
    if (e.target.className.match(/(\s|^)foobar(\s|$)/)) {
        //matches if the element has the class "foobar" in its classes list
    }
    if (e.target.id == 'baz') {
        //matches if the element has an id of "baz"
        //same syntax works for attributes like 'name', 'href', 'title', etc.
    }
    if (e.target instanceof HTMLLabelElement && e.target.attributes.for.value == 'baz') {
        //matches a <label> tag that has its 'for' attribute set to 'baz'
        //the element.attributes.attrName.value is the syntax for getting the value
        //    of any attribute that isn't available otherwise
    }
});
```

The problem with delegating the `mouseenter` event though is that it only fires when the element it is applied to is hovered over. In other words, if you attach a mouseenter event to the document, like in your jQuery code, it will only fire when the `document` is entered with the mouse, but not for any of the children. For making it work on the children, you'll need to use `mouseover`.

Comment: This is not the same. It must be a "live" listener, that fires on mouseenter of future created elements.

Comment: mouseover and mouseenter not the same, but it's better that nothing. Thank you!

Comment: They're not, no, but I believe that, going by [this bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6615), jQuery also makes delegated mouseenter events work via mouseover. In these kinds of situations, where you test if the event target has a certain property (such as `instanceof`), the way the two events work is identical, since the difference between mouseenter and mouseover is usually that mouseenter only fires when the element itself is mouseovered and mouseover fires for children too, but in this case, that is resolved via the `instanceof` test.

Comment: Addition: this is also how jQuery does it, as can be seen in [this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/auK46/3/), which is just a modified version of the fiddle that is included in the link I posted in my previous comment. As you can see, jQuery uses `mouseover` for the event binding, and then "disguises" it as `mouseenter` in their jQuery event object.

Answer (score 0):

**This optimizes compatibility across old and new browsers.**

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ht3HM/)

```
var links = document.links || document.anchors || document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    addEvent(links[i], 'mouseenter', action);
}

function addEvent(element, myEvent, fnc) {
    return ((element.attachEvent) ? element.attachEvent('on' + myEvent, fnc) : element.addEventListener(myEvent, fnc, false));
}

function action(evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event,
        link = (e.currentTarget) ? e.currentTarget : e.srcElement;
    link.style.color = "lime";
}
```

Comment: Not the same. What if new links will be created in the future?

Comment: You put the first 4 lines into a `function()` and when those links are created, you re-run the function.

Comment: I don't know when they will be created.

Comment: Then how do you know they are going to be created at all